# Comparing objects of different type with a shared property

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, realm

I have multiple sorted arrays that each has a specific type. I need to merge these sorted arrays together to make a sorted array of type Any. Even though the objects are different, each has a common property `date: Date` that I want to use for sorting.

Unfortunately, I can't subclass the original objects because I am using Realm (have to subclass from `Object`), which means I can't have any inheritance.

How would you go about altering the classes to merge and sort the arrays? I am unsure as to how to compare the objects in a way that isn't hacky. Very open to modifying the class (as long as to keep with Realm's requirements: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

Example code:

```swift
    import RealmSwift

    class Example1: Object {
        dynamic var text: String = ""
        dynamic var date: Date?

    }

    class Example2: Object {
        dynamic var num: Int = 0
        dynamic var date: Date?
    }

// there would be a sorted array of type Example1 and a sorted array of type Example2
// I would need to merge these two arrays and sort them based on the date property
```

Comment: How about implementing a protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you use protocols, you can start with something like this:

```
protocol DateProtocol {
    var date: Date? { get set }
}
```

Then make both classes conform to `DateProtocol` protocol.

After that you can treat your classes as *DateProtocol* and access their date property.

You can do something like this:

```
var mergedArray: [DateProtocol] = example1Array as! [DateProtocol] + example2Array as! [DateProtocol]
mergedArray.sorted({ $0.date > $1.date })
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! I had a feeling that I needed to use protocols, and this clarified a lot in my head about how to use them. Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? I don't have realm, but hopefully Object lets you create a dynamic var for Custom object.

```
protocol Custom {
    var date: Date? { get set }
}

class CustomObject: Custom {
    var data : Any?
    var date: Date?
    init (d : Any) {
        data = d
    }
}

let co : CustomObject = CustomObject(d: "Meow")
let co2 : CustomObject = CustomObject(d: 2)

// This should be Object, not NSObject, but I don't have Realm installed.
class RealmObj : NSObject {
    var obj : CustomObject? // Make dynamic in your code.
}

let ro = RealmObj()

ro.obj = co2
```